# Custom message for Type Mismatch validation error while using Spring Boot and Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, hibernate-validator

**Controller**

```java
public String dummyAction(@Valid @ModelAttribute DummyInputData inputData) {
        return "success";
    }
```

**Entity**

```java
public class DummyInputData {
    private Integer more;

    public Integer getMore() {
        return more;
    }
    
    public DummyInputData setMore(Integer more) {
        this.more = more;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Once I will send in POST a String in `more` field like `this is my test`, I will receive this error:

```java
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer' for property 'more'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"this is my test\"
```

I would like to change that message to something custom.

I followed other questions and tutorials. In the end, I tried this kind of overwriting in properties files, though it didn't work. File is properly loaded - I was able to overwrite other messages.

**Used declarations in messages properties file**

```java
typeMismatch.more=You provided invalid value
javax.validation.constraints.typeMismatch.more=You provided invalid value


javax.validation.constraints.typeMismatch.int={0} Value must be an integer
typeMismatch.int={0} Value must be an integer
javax.validation.constraints.typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer={0} must be an integer
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer={0} must be an integer
typeMismatch={0} is of invalid format
javax.validation.constraints.typeMismatch={0} is of invalid format
```

I'm aware that I'm able to use Controller Advice and catch `TypeMismatchException`, though I would prefer to add a custom message to the validation response. What then would be the proper approach of overwriting that generic type mismatch message?

Comment: can you please lookinto it https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html